# Weird ServiceConfigurationError when starting Hive CLI

Tags: hadoop, exception, hive

Edit: I can start Hive with no problem if I turn my Wi-Fi off.  That's probably useful information.

I am using Hive 2.0.0 on my personal laptop in pseudodistributed mode.  The last time I used Hive (a few days ago), everything worked normally as it always has been.  Between then and now, I have not touched my Hive installation.  I tried entering the CLI, and now am receiving the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider tachyon.hadoop.TFS could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2563)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:494)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:645)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at tachyon.Constants.<clinit>(Constants.java:328)
        at tachyon.hadoop.AbstractTFS.<clinit>(AbstractTFS.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: unallocated.barefruit.co.uk: unallocated.barefruit.co.uk: unknown error
        at org.spark-project.guava.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
        at tachyon.util.network.NetworkAddressUtils.getLocalIpAddress(NetworkAddressUtils.java:398)
        at tachyon.util.network.NetworkAddressUtils.getLocalHostName(NetworkAddressUtils.java:320)
        at tachyon.conf.TachyonConf.<init>(TachyonConf.java:122)
        at tachyon.conf.TachyonConf.<init>(TachyonConf.java:111)
        at tachyon.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:27)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: unallocated.barefruit.co.uk: unallocated.barefruit.co.uk: unknown error
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
        at tachyon.util.network.NetworkAddressUtils.getLocalIpAddress(NetworkAddressUtils.java:355)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: unallocated.barefruit.co.uk: unknown error
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
        ... 33 more
```

I have never heard of Tachyon before now.  And what is `unallocated.barefruit.co.uk`!?  This is very strange, and there is not much on the Internet that I found useful.  Can anyone take a wild guess as to why this would have happened out of the blue?

Comment: it seems like your hostname is not resolved properly , I guess it is resolved as 'unallocated.barefruit.co.uk' , can you check your host file entry /etc/hosts , also check for core-site proxy user configuration https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_hdfs_proxy_users.html

Comment: *"what is unallocated.barefruit.co.uk"* -- just Google it. Looks like it a kind of Adware that your internet provider uses to monetize your DNS requests.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I did Google it.  I guess I should've said, "What does DNS and HTTP error resolution have to do with Hive?"

Comment: My 2 cents: your Hadoop distro supports Tachyon *(a kind of new-generation RAM disk)*; the HDFS client registers automatically the Tachyon driver because it is in the CLASSPATH; some Tachyon property has a silly default value pointing to a host name (e.g. `s3.amazonaws.com` --  cf. https://github.com/opensignal/tachyon/blob/master/common/src/main/resources/tachyon-default.properties); and so the Tachyon driver initialization fires a DNS request.

Comment: Bottom line: weed out all the optional stuff that you don't need, e.g. Tachyon JARs + Amazon S3 JARs + Microsoft Azure JARs + whatever, and live happy ever after.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was alluded to in the comments, the issue arises because my ISP's DNS resolvers have a redirection service that redirects an unknown host to a sponsored page.  It's still unclear to me what this has to do with Hive, but anyway, the problem was fixed by going to (on my MacBook Pro) System Preferences>Network>Advanced>DNS and adding 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to the list of DNS servers.

In doing so, I'm using Google's DNS resolution service in lieu of my current DNS provider.